# create table in database using EF from our applictaion Dynamically

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Can we create table in database from our Web application dynamically using EF where user define fields for table.
I am working on MVC 4.

Is it possible ?
and if yes then how to do it.

Comment: You can use *Code First* approach.

Comment: I already uses code first approach for developing in my application.
And what to do this who to this dynamically this from my application. Where user have an interface for creating table.

Comment: Show what have you done or where you are stuck so that we could help. Else all we could do is direct you to some tutorials.

Comment: I wana made a page where user can have options to add new Item type to his library. So he can creat this type table in database.for example like If he wana add book item to the library so he can add field of to the book table like book_title, author etc.
and after creating this table he can store information of book in book table which is created by user.

Yet i can't done any thing for this it just an thought that can we do something like this using EF code first and mvc 4.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you understand by dynamic here.  Changing the runtime version of the Context isnt possible.

Generating, compiling, loading  NEW code is. So a new context, and POCO code can be declared. Compiled and loaded. All controlled by a piece of running code.

However, the ongoing lifecycle gets complicated. 
The use of code first migrations becomes tricky.
How to manage chnages to extensions in Prod.
How to merge ongoing dev and prod.
Managing the mapping in Fluent API in generated code is awful.
You cant do it all in Attributes.

The context backflips and automated migrations nightmares have cost me many a night.

Dealing with main build natural extensions and production/localised implementation extension gets VERY hard. You need to make sure they are incorporated back into the build.

And a must is You need to know how to manage different contexts on the same DB at the same time.

I have exactly this UNFINISHED project at the moment. I have put it on hold until we are on EF6.
I expect to spend several weeks on this topic alone.
And Im still not sure i want to continue down this path.
I am seriously considering moving to a meta Data / bucket data approach.

So It is possible but difficult (In my opinion at least). It will be  easier in EF6 due to the multiple context support. But it will still suffer from most of these issues and  require code generation and compilation still.

Good luck...

Comment: I think also same it's so complicated.
How to manage DBContext at run it and add DBSet to DBContext.