# C # entity framework generate entities from a JSON

Tags: c#, sql, json, web-services, entity-framework

I have a web service that generates a very complex json structure
with many children, I wonder if it is possible to create tables from this json structure and future update these tables with entity framework.

have a basic knowledge of how to generate table from code first

Comment: do you mean dynamically create the Tables? http://stackoverflow.com/q/17967281/1347784

Comment: Couldn't you first deserialize the json to an object and work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This you are searching for 
See the documentation on the site

http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/

There is also a web version of the software

http://json2csharp.com/